# My one test case is not passing .Giving TLE for one case

Tags: java, string, object, time, stack

Problem Statement is from hackerrank.

**Name:** Simple text Editor
**Description:** I has taken a stackNode.in stackNode i used three variables top is for previous operation performed operate is k and s for storing the string which was either deleted or appended in previous operation.

**Link to the problem** 
: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/simple-text-editor/problem?isFullScreen=false

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class StackNode
{
int top;
int operat;
String s;
}
public class Solution 
{
static String S="";
static Stack<StackNode> stack=new Stack<>();
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=sc.nextInt();
    while(t-- >0)
    {
        int operation=sc.nextInt();
        if(operation == 1)
        {
            String st=sc.next();
            S=S+st;
            StackNode node=new StackNode();
            node.top=operation;
            node.s=st;
            stack.push(node);
        }
        else
        if(operation == 2)
        {
            int k=sc.nextInt();
            delete(k,operation);
        }
        else
        if(operation == 3)
        {
            int k=sc.nextInt();
            print(k);
        }
        else
        if(operation == 4)
           undo();
    }
}
static void delete(int k,int operation)
{
    StackNode node=new StackNode();
    node.top=operation;
    node.operat=k;
    if(S.length() < k)
    {
        node.s=S;
        S="";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        node.s=S.substring(S.length()-k);
        S=S.substring(0,S.length()-k);
    }
    stack.push(node);
    }
    static void print(int k)
{
    if(k<=S.length())
       System.out.println(S.charAt(k-1));
}
static void undo()
{
    if(stack.isEmpty())
      return;
    StackNode node=stack.pop();
    if(node.top == 1)
    {
        S=S.substring(0,S.length()-node.s.length());
    }
    else
    if(node.top == 2)
    {
        S=S+node.s;
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: As a complete aside, `java.util.Stack` is outdated. I’d use `ArrayList` or `ArrayDeque` for the stack. It probably makes no difference on the *time limit exceeded*. For a slight optimization don’t store the appended string but only the length of it, that’s enough for undoing the appending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** Copying the entire editor content on each append and each delete operation takes a long time when the string is long. **Solution:** Instead of keeping the editor content in a `String` use a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`.

The content of the editor may be up to a million chars. Each of the following code lines copies this content into a new `String`:

```
        S=S+st;

    S=S.substring(0,S.length()-k);

    S=S.substring(0,S.length()-node.s.length());

    S=S+node.s;
```

When instead you append to or delete from a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`, the characters not involved in the operation can stay in place.

Other possible slight optimizations:

1. On the undo stack don’t store the appended string but only the length of it. The length suffices for undoing the append operation.
2. Use a `switch` statement for selecting the right operation rather than chained if-else.

> is there any difference between switch and chained if-else in terms of
>   time complexity and space complexity

In most cases switch on an `int` value should be faster than chained if-else.

**Documentation link:** [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: is there any difference between switch and chained if-else in terms of time complexity and space complexity